# Sort collection by a parameter

Tags: anylogic

i'm trying to sort descending a collection C of agents.
My agent P has got a parameter p1 ( an integer between 0 and 4, which is assigned via a distribution at the creation of the agent itself)
As a new agent is created it's also add to the C.
What i'm trying to to is to add the agent and then sort descending the collection based on parameter p1.
example:
collection is like this:

```
List<P> C:{ P1; 
    P2;
    P3}
```

Where:

```
P1.p1=0
P2.p1=3
P3.p1=0
```

What i want to obtain is the collection ordered as follow:

```
C:{P2;
   P1;
   P3;}
```

How can I do it?
Thank everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use sortDescending(population, value)

so in your case it would be something like

```
List <P> sorted =sortDescending(C, p->p.p1);
```